# Querying a function in functions.php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a jQuery code that is going to check when the user is near the bottom of the page. That's not the problem though. This jQuery is going to send a AJAX request, giving it some details on what to load when the user is near the bottom of the page. The code looks a bit like this at the moment:

```
$("<div>").load('?ajax=y&offset=something', function() {

    $(".empty-div").append($(this));

    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('after', $(document).height()); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('after', $(window).height()); }, 0);


});
```

My main problem is that I don't know what to query or how to go about sending the information to the PHP function in functions.php. For example, I have at the moment this as my PHP function (until it's working):

```
function get_posts_page() {


if(isset($_GET['offset'])) {
     echo"Hello!";
}

}
```

I'm aware the wordpress has `add_action` and all that but I have no idea what I would apply as an action to either function to make the PHP recieve the data the Javascript is sending. Is there a URL where all functions are parsed or something? Thanks for any help in advance. So how do I get the data from the Javascript to the PHP function in functions.php, in my theme directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a video to show you how to use the `add_action` request in WordPress. You can [watch it here](http://screenr.com/9dk).

Here's my javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#branding img').click(function() {

  $.post('<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
    action: 'my_unique_action',
    offset: 5
  }, function(data) {
    $('#content').prepend('<p>' + data + '</p>');
  });

});


</script>
```

And the php that I used in `functions.php`

```
// Make sure it runs when the user is logged in,
// and when they are not.
add_action('wp_ajax_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');

function get_offset() {
  if( isset($_POST['offset']) ) {
    echo 'Your ajax request was successful. Here was your offset: <strong>' . $_POST['offset'] . '</strong>';
  }

  die;
}
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to call a PHP function from Javascript, correct?

You'll need some logic on some page which calls `get_posts_page()`. Either you can **create a new page** `getPostsPage.php?offset=` or you can put some logic in `functions.php`, something like

```
if(isset($_GET['function']) {
    switch($_GET['function']) {
        case 'get_posts_page':
            get_posts_page();
    }
}
```

However, the former approach is recommended; you don't want someone to be able to modify the `function` parameter and access `deleteAllPosts()` maliciously.

Therefore:

```
// getPostsPage.php
require PATH . 'functions.php';
get_posts_page(); //checks $_GET['offset']
```

And remember to fail gracefully (do not expose an error message) if 'offset' is not set, or whatever.

Comment: See @Baylor Rae's answer as it is the standard way of doing AJAX with WordPress, rolling your own requires you to handle too many things (like security) that are automatic if you do it the standard way.